# Question regarding the use of the term "critical point"

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Given a function, $f(x)=\sqrt{4x-x^2}$, what does it mean to find its critical points?

Assuming that the domain of the function in question is not explicitly stated, am I right to say that this function is well-defined only when $0 \leq x \leq 4$?

If that is the case, are points $x=0, x=2, x=4$ considered the critical points of $f$? Or is the critical point just at $x=2$?

Comment: A "critical point" is a point in the domain of function, say $x_0$ while "critical value", is the value of the function at the critical point ie, $f(x_0)$.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say "find its critical points". I'll edit the question accordingly

Comment: Minor point: assuming that the square root of a negative number is undefined, then the function is well defined $\iff 0 \leq (4x - x^2) = x(4-x).$  Let $g(x) = [x(4-x)]$.  For $x \geq 0, g(x) \geq 0 \iff 4 \geq x.$  For $x < 0$, the first factor of $g(x)$ must be negative, and the 2nd factor must be positive.  Therefore, if $x < 0$, then $g(x)$ must be negative.  This agrees with your assertion; I simply wasn't sure how you arrived at your assertion.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)#:%7E:text=Critical%20point%20is%20a%20wide,derivative%20is%20equal%20to%20zero.):

> When dealing with functions of a real variable, a critical point is a
> point in the domain of the function where the function is either not
> differentiable or the derivative is equal to zero

In your case the function is not differentiable in $x=0$ and $x=4$. On the other hand:

$$f'(x)=\frac{2-x}{\sqrt{4x-x^{2}}}$$

Therefore $f'(x)=0$ only if $x=2$, that critical point would correspond to the maximum of the function in the domain $x\in [0,4]$

Comment: If thats the case, then $x=0, x=4$ shouldn't be considered as critical points because critical points are located IN the interior of the domain, and should not be located at the end points correct? 

If so, is it also right to say that the only local extreme value is the local maximum at $x=2$?

Comment: Take into account that in order to be differentiable, a function has to be continuous, therefore the function is not differentiable at the limits of its domain (the limit when $x \rightarrow 0^{-}$ or $x\rightarrow4^{+}$ does not exist), thus the boundary of the domain is formed by critical points